# JavaScript: parseInt(1.15*100) = 114 WHY?

Tags: javascript, parseint

So the behavior of parseInt here seems to me to be so bad that I just don't know what to think...

```
parseInt(1.15*100) = 114
```

Comment: Have you examined `1.15*100` alone? Hint: `parseInt` isn't the problem. Floating-point multiplication is.

Comment: `1.15 * 100 = 114.999999` but `1.17*100 = 117` and `1.18*100 = 118`

Comment: `parseInt` stringifies non-string arguments and then reads input until it encounters anything inconsistent with an integer (i.e., here, everything right of the decimal point is ignored), so we end up with `114`.

Comment: It's very tough to express `1.15` in binary `m * 2^e` format, just like it's very tough to express the simplified form of `10/3` in decimal format.